# get report G Suite account

Tags: hangouts-api, google-hangouts

I'm trying to get google report activity by calling `https://www.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/activity/users/all/applications/meet`

I created a service account and I have to use the generated `private key` (json file) as `access token`.

My code was:

```
String PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/activity/users/all/applications/meet?eventName=call_ended&maxResults=10&access_token=";
        String graph = "";
        try
        {
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject data = (JSONObject) parser.parse(
                  new FileReader("C:/Users/Administrateur/Desktop/GoogleApis/Interoperability-googleApis/target/classes/my-first-project-274515-361633451f1c.json"));//path to the JSON file.

            String json_private_key = data.toJSONString();

            URL urUserInfo = new URL(PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL + json_private_key);
            HttpURLConnection connObtainUserInfo = (HttpURLConnection) urUserInfo.openConnection();
            if (connObtainUserInfo.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {
                StringBuilder sbLines = new StringBuilder("");

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connObtainUserInfo.getInputStream(), "utf-8"));
                String strLine = "";
                while ((strLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sbLines.append(strLine);
                }
                graph = sbLines.toString();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("--------------- Result: " + graph);
```

but I got null value.

Could you please tell me what I misses ?.
Big Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Access Token is not part of your request URL. You can read [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) about the OAuth2 protocol and how it works.

However, Google built an API that enables you to authenticate your requests without worrying about the underlying OAuth2 process.
You should be using the Java Google Reports API to access activities. [Here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/quickstart/java) you can find the Java Quickstart that will help you with the first set up of your Java Application.

Here the Java translation of what you are trying to do, using the Google Reports API:

```java
Reports service = new Reports.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                  .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                  .build();

String userKey = "all";
String applicationName = "meet";
String eventName = "call_ended";
Activities result = service.activities().list(userKey, applicationName)
                    .setEventName(eventName)
                    .setMaxResults(10)
                    .execute();
```

### Edit:

Be sure to use the last version of the Java API package. You can find the Java API docs here: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/admin/reports_v1/java/latest/

If you are using Gradle be sure to have this line in the dependencies parameter.

```
dependencies {
   ...
   compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-admin-reports:reports_v1-rev89-1.25.0'
}
```

### References

[OAuth2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)

[Google Reports API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/quickstart/java)

Comment: Hello Sir @Alessandro, thanks a lot for your reply. I tried that many times, but I got that exception : `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter applicationName must conform to the pattern (admin)|(calendar)|(drive)|(login)|(mobile)|(token)|(groups)|(saml)`. I don't know why that same code works as well with `login` , `calendar`, ... but failed with `meet` **applicationName**.
. Could you please help me solving that issue ?. Big thanks.

Comment: Looks like you are using an outdated version of the Java Api. Try with the last one: `'com.google.apis:google-api-services-admin-reports:reports_v1-rev89-1.25.0'`
I edited my answer to help other users on this.